# Is it possible to show the chart if the value of array bracket is null or empty in the HighChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have problem regarding on my HighChart because when my json response is null or empty the chart is not shown, if the response has a value the bar is show. so the question **is it possible in the highchart if the value of json response is null?**

**My Column Chart show the output like this:**

[image: HighChart Output]

**Response:**

[image: response]

My HighChart Function:

```
    categories = [],
seriesNames = ['MR', 'MR_HIT', 'MR_HIT_PERCENTAGE'],
series = [];

$.getJSON('ajax/ams_sla_report_chart.php', function(data,name){

    data.forEach(function(arr) {
        arr.forEach(function(el, i) {

            if (i === 0) {
                categories.push(el);
            } else if (series[i - 1]) {
                series[i - 1].data.push(el);
            } else {                    
                series.push({
                     name: seriesNames[i - 1],
                    data: [el]
                });
            }
        });
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'containers',
            type: 'column',
            inverted: false    
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                minPointLength: 3
            }
        },
        title: {
           text: 'Priority Based on SLA'
        },
        series:series       
    });

    // chart.series[0].name="SOLVED MR";
    // chart.series[1].name="TOTAL MR HIT";
    // chart.series[2].name="TOTAL MR HIT PERCENTAGE";


    function showValues() {
        $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
        $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
        $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
    }

    // Activate the sliders
    $('#sliders_eng input').on('input change', function () {
        chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = parseFloat(this.value);
        showValues();
        chart.redraw(false);
    });

    showValues();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible to draw chart if series is empty. You can add an if clause and draw chart only if `series` have data. Else show a different message

```
$.getJSON('ajax/ams_sla_report_chart.php', function(data, name) {

  data.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(el, i) {

      if (i === 0) {
        categories.push(el);
      } else if (series[i - 1]) {
        series[i - 1].data.push(el);
      } else {
        series.push({
          name: seriesNames[i - 1],
          data: [el]
        });
      }
    });
  });
  if (series.length !== 0) { // show chart only if series has data
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'containers',
        type: 'column',
        inverted: false
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: categories
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          minPointLength: 3
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Priority Based on SLA'
      },
      series: series
    });

    // chart.series[0].name="SOLVED MR";
    // chart.series[1].name="TOTAL MR HIT";
    // chart.series[2].name="TOTAL MR HIT PERCENTAGE";


    function showValues() {
      $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
      $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
      $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
    }

    // Activate the sliders
    $('#sliders_eng input').on('input change', function() {
      chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = parseFloat(this.value);
      showValues();
      chart.redraw(false);
    });

    showValues();
  } // end of if
  else {
    // add a code to ask user to slet user know that chart cannot be drawn

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the `no-data-to-display` module to show a message on a chart when there is no data:

```
lang: {
    noData: "no-data-to-display"
},
noData: {
    ...
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8acxywjv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData